# Add pygame module in PyCharm IDE

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal, pygame, pycharm

I've downloaded `pygame-1.9.1release.tar.gz` from the Pygame website. I extracted and installed it and it's working fine in the command line Python interpreter in Terminal (Ubuntu). But I want to install it for some IDE, like PyCharm. How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean *"install it for some IDE"*? Is your PyCharm project using an interpreter (see e.g. https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/quickstart/configuring_interpreter.html) that has access to `pygame`? Is it using the same one as the command line (use `which python` to find out)?

Comment: Got it after interpreter configuration. Thanks for the advise. But it's still not working for IDLE(using python2.7) because it has it's own interpreter.

Comment: If you want to run IDLE with a specific interpreter, use `/path/to/python -m idlelib`

Comment: Yes, on the command line.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, you don't have to download it for PyCharm here. You probably know how it checks your code. Through the interpreter! You don't need to use complex command lines or anything like that. You need to is:

- Download the appropriate interpreter *with* PyGame included
- Open your PyCharm IDE (Make sure it is up to date)
- Go to `File`
- Press `Settings` (Or Ctrl + Alt + S)
- **Double click** on the option that looks like `Project: Name_of_Project`
- Click on `Project Interpreter`
- Choose the interpreter you want to use that ***includes*** PyGame as a module
- Save your options

And you are ready to go! Here is an alternate (I have never done this, please try to test it)

- Add PyGame in the same folder as your PyCharm file (Your PyCharm stuff is always in
  a specific file placed by **you** during installation/upgrade)
  Please consider putting your PyCharm stuff inside a folder for easy access.

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 15):

For PyCharm 2017 do the following:

- File - Settings
- Double click on your project name
- Select Project Interpreter
- Click on green + button on the right side of the window
- Type Pygame in search window
- Click Install package.

Not I'm saying that the answers above won't work, but it might be frustrating to a newbie to do command line magic.

Comment: After I click install package I have an error "Error occured when installing package 'Pygame'"
Error occured:
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

How can I fix it sir?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using PyCharm and you are on a Windows 10 machine use the following instructions:

1. Click on the Windows start menu and type *cmd* and click on the Command Prompt icon.
2. Use the command *pushd* to navigate to your PyCharm project which should be located in your user folder on the C:\ drive. Example: *C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\project name\venv\Scripts*.

   (If you are unsure go to the settings within PyCharm and navigate to the Python Interpreter settings. This should show you the file path for the interpreter that your project is using. *Credit to Anthony Pham for instructions to navigate to interpreter settings.*)

   HINT: Use copy and paste in the command prompt to paste in the file path.
3. Use the command *pip install pygame* and the pip program will handle the rest for you.
4. Restart you Pycharm and you should now be able to import *pygame*

Hope this helps. I had a fun time trying to find out the correct way to get it installed, so hopefully this helps someone out in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out!

1. Put the `.whl` file in `C:\Program Files\Anaconda3`
2. While in the folder, click on the blue **File** tab in the upper left corner of the Window Explorer (assuming you're using Windows)
3. Click on **Open Windows PowerShell as administrator**
4. Write or just copy and paste: `py -m pip install pygame`
5. It should start installing
6. Done!

I hope it works for you. I know it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

I already had pygame installed with python38-32
since its working just fine with it. I used this version of python us my project interpreter.

1.File -settings

2.according to your settings look for project interpreter

3.click on your current project interpreter and click on the add symbol

4.choose system interpreter

5.select the python version thats works with pygame for you

6.Note: some versions of pygame don't work with some versions of python be sure
of what are you doing.

7.hope it works.