# Increasing the difficulty of the guess the number game every time the user wins (python)

Tags: python, pygame

So my friends and I are all currently in a python class and we were looking through a book called "Invent Your Own Computer Games with Python". We found an example where the book explains how to create a Guess the Number Game and decided to mess around with it.

We want to create a function that increases the difficulty every time the user successfully guesses the correct number generated by the computer.

I was thinking that perhaps we could need a counter to keep track of how many times the user successfully wins a round and then (if they won) increases range of numbers.
For example:
    easy = (1, 5)
    medium = (1, 10)
    hard = (1, 20)

Here's what I've done:

```
# This is a guess the number game.
import random

# create function for level difficulty
# The difficulty will be multiplied by 2 each time the user passes a level

def puzzle(difficulty):
    while counter <= 3:
        return difficulty * 2

counter = 0
guessestaken = 0

while guessestaken < 3:

    while counter < 3:
        level = puzzle(3)
        number = random.randint(1, level)
        print("I am thinking of a number between 1 and " + str(level))

        print("Take a guess.")
        guess = input()
        guess = int(guess)

        guessestaken += 1
        if guess < number:
            print("Your guess is too low.")

        if guess > number:
        print("Your guess is too high.")

        if guess == number:
            break
        counter += 1

    if guess == number:
        guessestaken = str(guessestaken)
        print ("Fantastic! You guessed my number in " + guessestaken + " guesses!")

    if guess != number:
        number = str(number)
        print("Sorry, The number I was thinking of was " + number)
```

I'm new to python and just barely learned about functions like two days ago. Any kind of help is welcomed.

Comment: You approach generally sounds right, but is there a specific question here? You might want to consider posting on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if it's a code review you are after.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear on my question. My questions are: How would I exactly execute my concept of using a counter? And why isn't my range of numbers increasing when the player wins a level? Thank you for the advice! I will definitely check that website out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work:

1. Make a variable called, say, times_won at the beginning. Each time the person wins,
   `times_won += 1`

BONUS: Do the same thing, but with a variable called times_lost and tick that up each time they lose.

2. Now it is up to you. You could change the difficulty like this:

   `level = puzzle(times_won+1*2)`

   This would make it so that it automatically goes up the more the player wins. Or how about this:

   `curr_dificulty = 5
   if #player_won:
       curr_dificulty += 4`

   This and other variations would increase it based on wins as well, but in a different way. You could also make it so that losing eases up the difficulty. This part is really up to you.

P.S. The tag "pygame" you used is actually referring to games made using a down-loadable library that you can import into your code, not games made with python in general. It makes games with actual graphics, you should try it out!

P.P.S. in case you didn't know, the weird syntax I made above with the *#player_won* and the fact that the assignment of *curr_dificulty* is out of place is because I used pseudo-code. It basically gives the idea, but you need to do the actual code yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Yeah, I was having a hard time figuring out why my counter wouldn't work or even how to get it to work. I appreciate your pseudocode and will test it out for sure. I definitely have a better idea of what to do now.

Comment: P.S. haha thanks for telling me that! Would that library work with Pycharm? I'm such a newbie lol but hey, we all start somewhere, right?

Comment: P.P.S Yes, I did know that but I appreciate you taking the time to tell me.

Comment: @Vanessa Salinas [Answer to your P.S.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453854/add-pygame-module-in-pycharm-ide) Also, please accept the answer if I helped you. Your welcome!