# Running a game which uses Pygame doesn't work in pycharm, but will work when run from terminal

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

When running a basic game, such as the one below, the screen will not update when ran in pycharm. Not even the background colour will load. However when run from terminal the program works fine. Why is this?

Note: I have installed Pygame using the pycharm package manager

```py
import sys, pygame
pygame.init()

size = width, height = 320, 240
speed = [2, 2]
black = 0, 0, 0

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

ball = pygame.image.load("ship.bmp")
ballrect = ball.get_rect()

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

    ballrect = ballrect.move(speed)
    if ballrect.left < 0 or ballrect.right > width:
        speed[0] = -speed[0]
    if ballrect.top < 0 or ballrect.bottom > height:
        speed[1] = -speed[1]

    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(ball, ballrect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453854/add-pygame-module-in-pycharm-ide

Answer (score 0):

Looks like interpreter problem, go to File->Settings->Project Interpreter->add(+ symbol) and install PyGame, or choose default(one on which it's running) enviroment. Should work