# Pygame could not be resolved

Tags: python, pygame

import pygame is underlined saying pygame could not be resolved.

Yet, when I launch my program, I have this message :

> c:\Users\Guillaume\PycharmProjects\Learn\Snake.py pygame 2.1.2
> (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.10.2) Hello from the pygame community.
> https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html

And when I run `python -m pip install pygame --user`

> WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip
> (c:\python310\lib\site-packages) WARNING: Ignoring invalid
> distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages) WARNING: Ignoring
> invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages) WARNING:
> Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
> Requirement already satisfied: pygame in
> c:\python310\lib\site-packages (2.1.2) WARNING: Ignoring invalid
> distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages) WARNING: Ignoring
> invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages) WARNING:
> Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
> WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -
> (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)

So it seems like pygame is working.

Though my window won't pop up, anyone ?

```
import pygame

def drawGrid(w, rows, surface):
    sizeBtwn = w // rows

    x = 0
    y = 0
    for l in range(rows):
        x = x + sizeBtwn
        y = y + sizeBtwn

        pygame.draw.line(surface, (255,255,255), (x,0),(x,w))
        pygame.draw.line(surface, (255,255,255), (0,y),(w,y))

def redrawWindow(surface):
    global rows, width
    surface.fill((0,0,0))
    drawGrid(width,rows,surface)
    pygame.display.update()

def main():
    global rows, width
    width=500
    rows=20
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((width,width))
    flag=True

    clock=pygame.time.Clock()

    while flag:
        pygame.time.delay(50) #time
        clock.tick(10) #frame
        redrawWindow(win)
```

Comment: Which version of python is your IDE using? Probably a different one to the one launched from your command line. Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28467215/2280890) will help you.

Comment: python 3.10.2, tried on both visual studio or git bash for windows

Answer (score 0):

I just solved a problem. You just have to write at the bottom (outside of the def main()) main() and keep the rest as it is.

```
import pygame

def drawGrid(w, rows, surface):
    sizeBtwn = w // rows
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for l in range(rows):
        x = x + sizeBtwn
        y = y + sizeBtwn
        pygame.draw.line(surface, (255,255,255), (x,0),(x,w))
        pygame.draw.line(surface, (255,255,255), (0,y),(w,y))

def redrawWindow(surface):
    global rows, width
    surface.fill((0,0,0))
    drawGrid(width,rows,surface)
    pygame.display.update()

def main():
    global rows, width
    width=500
    rows=20
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((width,width))
    flag=True
    clock=pygame.time.Clock()
    while flag:
        pygame.time.delay(50) #time
        clock.tick(10) #frame
        redrawWindow(win)
main()
```